# How to change screen resolution of Thinkpad x300?

Tags: 11.04, resolution, thinkpad, screen

I think that the maximum resolution I can get is 8192x8192.

Could you tell me how can I *SAFELY* increase the screen resolution?

Actually I wanted to try with `xrandr` command, but I am afraid that it may create some problems as there is not much support for the video drivers (Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960) of my machine. I am not sure though.

The output of `xrandr` command on my Thinkpad x300 running Ubuntu 11.04 is as follows.
    $ xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1440 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 287mm x 180mm
   1440x900       60.0*+   59.9     50.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9
```

VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Some more information:

```
$ uname -a

Linux user-thinkpad 2.6.38-8-generic-pae #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 05:17:09 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the maximum resolution for your Thinkpad x300 is 1440x900, limited by the screen in your laptop. But don't worry, that's already a very nice resolution for 13 inch laptops.

The listed 8192 x 8192 is the maximum amount of pixels your video card can handle, or the maximum "virtual resolution". This gives you room to plug in external monitors. Horizontally and vertically, you can support up to 8192 pixels, so you can plug in a 1920x1080 monitor, which will make your total virtual resolution (1440+1920)x1080 or 3360x1080.

Comment: Yeah.., you are right. I have just tried higher resolutions than 1440x900 with xrandr. Though it is working, firefox browser window doesn't fit in the screen and it doesn't look good. Thanks.